# Wicket - Expand non visible tree node

Tags: tree, wicket-1.6

I would like to expand a tree node that is not visible in my DefaultNestedTree(wicket 6).
I have learned that the AbstractTree class can not expand non visible tree nodes (from source: Does nothing if the given node is currently not visible)

Is there any way i am not aware of to easily expand a tree node that is not visible?

Walking up all nodes (via e.g. getParent()) is in my opinion not a verry satisfying option.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My answer based on Wicket 6.9.0 sources.

"AbstractTree" holds nodes state in model object - `Set<T>`.
On calls to "expand" and "collapse" affected node added or removed from model object.

So possible solutions:

1. Use "expand".
2. Modify model object `Set<T>` directly.